# Is DeviceCheck or indentifierForVendor safe?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, security, devicecheck

I am planning on using `DeviceCheck`or `indentifierForVendor` to ensure that the same device is not being used to redeem multiple times the same gift (free money for example sake) offered to new users. I am wondering however, if it is possible to trick this system on a jailbroken device? Or using a custom simulator or a botnet (do iOS botnets exist?)?

Comment: I'm also wondering how easy it is for a hacker to bypass DeviceCheck today. If it is a matter of changing the bundle ID, should we do a check for valid bundle ID in the app.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think it is possible to change the bundle identifier, resign the app and side load it to your device.

This will change the change the identifier for both `DeviceCheck` and `indentifierForVendor`.

Now, for this to really affect you, the user needs to get a hold of the ipa. Which is getting increasingly difficult with the newer versions of iOS.

If you are interested in trying what I've discussed, refer to this link.
https://coderwall.com/p/qwqpnw/resign-ipa-with-new-cfbundleidentifier-and-certificate

And probably AirSign (much easier). Its a paid app for the Mac. https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/51845/airsign

Comment: I'm sorry if this is old but how do users get a hold of our ipa files or the app's source code and re-sign them?